# data.table: parallel execution of row-wise function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

I want to apply a function to some colums in every row of a `data.table`. I do this using something like this:

```
require(data.table)

## create some random data
n = 1000
p = 1000
set.seed(1)
data.raw <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow = n, ncol = p)
rownames(data.raw) <- lapply(1:n, FUN = function(x, length)paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), length, replace=TRUE), collapse=""), length = 10)
colnames(data.raw) <- samples <- paste0("X", 1:n)
data.t   <- data.table(data.raw)
data.t[, id := rownames(data.raw)]
setkey(data.t, id)

# apply function for each row
f <- function(x){return(data.frame(result1 = "abc", result2 = "def"))}
data.t[, c("result1", "result2") := f(.SD), .SDcols = samples, by = id]
```

is there any (easy) way to parallelize the execution of `f` for every `id` in the data.table?
I know that there are some questions here about parallelization of `data.table`, but I couldn't find a good answer in any of these.

Comment: I would first check if this function of yours could be vectorized (I hope you are not really running `data.frame` per row). Secondly, did you really search on Google for this? How about https://github.com/jangorecki/big.data.table (written by one of data.table developers), for instance?

Comment: The function cannot be vectorized. Each row contains one variable for which I run linear regressions against data that is in another `data.frame`. Basically, what I want is a data.table version of `adply`.